# Gmail Node Quickstart redirect_uri

Tags: gmail-api

After following the directions at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs I have found that I get an error in my console that looks as follows

[image]

This tells me that I need to be including some redirect_uri to the console, but the tutorial appears to give no counsel on what I should be doing to get there so that information makes it into the json file downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

The first download for some reason didn't include the redirect_uris.  I redownloaded the file and now it works